# Kafka cluster logging levels

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to figure out the log level for a Kafka cluster. Does the log4j.properties configuration of the cluster comply with these assumptions or not? I cannot find any info regarding logging levels at apache Kafka web page.

```
https://www.javatpoint.com/log4j-logging-levels
ALL < TRACE < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL < OFF
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the log4j file is the source of truth for server log levels.

Kafka website doesn't need to repeat information from the log4j site...